# Eclipse Java Projects in the Cloud

Tags: java, eclipse, cloud

I would like use Eclipse projects from my home and office and I don't want export/import them each time before use. Is there any way I can store/use my Eclipse Java project from the cloud like cloud foundry.

Please let me know the options.

Comment: Google "online code repositories". Things like Google Code, BitBucket, FogBugz/KilnHG, etc. Those are the things you're looking for. To use it, you'll need to familiarize yourself with their version of source control, like Mercurial or Git, but with it, you can not only store stuff on their servers, but take advantage of source control as well.

Comment: I think they mean not use a repository, map eclipses workspace to an online storage service?

Comment: @Mark If so, then shove it in a Dropbox folder and it's done. But then you won't have revision control, which is nice.

Comment: Yep, map a drive to your online storage service, then change your workspace or project directory to that drive and away you go.  Will require a decent connection though else you'll end up with really annoying lag every time you save/compile anything.    Personally I'd just use a git like bitbucket etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could move your Eclipse folder inside a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) folder.

Added bonus: access your project from anywhere.

You could also use [GitHub](https://github.com/), but then your source code will be open to the community unless you pay for one of their "plans".

Also, consider using [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), which isn't known as well, but is free.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use GitHub to store all my code, and use the Git integration within Eclipse to push and pull code to the master version on GitHub whenever necessary.

This has a few advantages:

- I can use a standard Eclipse setup with minimal customisation
- I can work offline (no need to store the actual current workspace in the cloud)
- The git integration within Eclipse is very good
- It integrates well with work done by others (pull requests etc.)
- I can be working on different branches on my laptop and desktop, merging when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answers given to others, I've setup an SVN repository on my Dropbox. It's very easy to do and, when using Ivy, it doesn't take much space.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Git Annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/not/) as well which offers a cool set of features worth checking out.